# Check if one variable has this value do something

Tags: php, if-statement

How can i check if one variable has this value do something.Example:

```
$price=$_POST['price'];

if ($price!=90 or $price!=104 or $price!=115 or $price!=120)
{
echo 'not true';
}
else
{
echo 'do something';
}
```

So if the post value has one of those four values do something.

Comment: Wrap your code inside `if(isset($_POST['price'])){...}`.

Comment: And what is the problem now?

Comment: depends on if your form's kosher and the element for it. No way to give a definite answer here. You should also check if it's numeric. and if being run inside the same page as your form.

Comment: Use:  $price=$_POST['price'];

if ($price==90 or $price==104 or $price==115 or $price==120)
{
echo 'do something';
}
else
{
echo 'not true';
}

Comment: gotta love guesswork huh?

Comment: *"and the forecast for this evening, will be dark.*" - Well we know that George. Now, how about for "today"? Show us your HTML form man.

Comment: i have post my answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

`$price!=90 or $price!=104`   will allways be true. You have to do this with the `and` operator

```
$price=$_POST['price'];

if ($price!=90 && $price!=104 && $price!=115 && $price!=120)
{
    echo 'not true';
}
else
{
    echo 'do something';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your checking values in an array and do the checking as follows:

```
        $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : false;

        $exist = array(90, 104, 115, 120);

        if (!in_array($price, $exist)) {
            echo 'not true';
        } else {
            echo 'do something';
        }
```